# I receive this error while trying to implement JWT Authentication, Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am receiving this error

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I am trying to use JWT along with reduxtoolkit and react but when i entered the correct username and password i received this error.

```
function Login() {
    const history=useHistory()
    const dispatch=useDispatch()
    const loginToken=useSelector(loginTokenSelector)
    const {register,handleSubmit,errors}=useForm()
    const onSubmit=data=>{
        dispatch(createLoginToken({
            username:data.username,
            password:data.password
        }))
        const isAuthenticated=localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
            ?true:false
        if(isAuthenticated) history.push('/')      
    }
    return (
        <Container>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

                <LoginContainer>        
                <InfoCard>
                    <TextHeader>Dawr Manager</TextHeader>
                    <TextHeader>The Complete Inventory Management</TextHeader>
                    <TextHeader>Point of Sale</TextHeader>
                    <TextHeader>Software</TextHeader>
                    <TextHeader>CLD Technologies</TextHeader>
                </InfoCard>                          
                <LoginCard>
                    {console.log('access token',loginToken.access)}
                    {loginToken.access==='rejected'&&loginToken.access!==''?'Incorrect UserName or Password':''}
                    {loginToken.access!=='rejected'&&loginToken.access!==''
                        ?localStorage.setItem('accessToken',loginToken.access):''}
                    {loginToken.access!=='rejected'&&loginToken.access!==''
                        ?localStorage.setItem('refreshToken',loginToken.refresh):''}
                    {loginToken.access!=='rejected'&&loginToken.access!==''?history.push('/'):''}

                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <NameField
                        name='username'
                        placeholder='User Name'
                        label='User Name'
                        error={!!errors.username}
                        helperText={!!errors.username?'User Name is required':''}
                        inputRef={register({
                        required:true,
                        maxLength:100
                        })}  
                    />

                    <PasswordField
                        name='password'
                        type='password'
                        placeholder='password'
                        label='Password'
                        error={!!errors.password}
                        helperText={!!errors.password?'Password is required':''}
                        inputRef={register({
                        required:true,
                        maxLength:100
                        })} 
                        
                    />
                    <ButtonSection>
                        <Button
                            type='submit'
                            color='primary'
                            variant='contained'
                            
                        >
                            Login
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            color='secondary'
                            variant='contained'
                        >
                            Clear
                        </Button>
                        </ButtonSection>
                    </LoginCard>
                </LoginContainer>
                
                </form>
                
        </Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the submit function on render.
Wrap it in a new function:

```
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```